# Query XML Column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a XML Column with this format:

```
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>SubscriberBalanceBefore</name>
            <value>
              <string>0.0</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>TimeStamp</name>
            <value>
              <dateTime.iso8601>20200812T12:31:10</dateTime.iso8601>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>Subsc riberMSISDN</name>
            <value>
              <string>83000000</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>TransactionID</name>
            <value>
              <string>8035768</string>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I expect to have results like the table bellow:

```
-------------------------
name      | TransactionID
----------|---------------
830000000 | 8035768
```

I have tried use `CROSS` and `OUTER APPLY` but it's not working:

```
SELECT 
    X.Y.value('(name)[3]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as NAME_FIELD,
    X.Y.value('(value/string)[4]', 'varchar(max)') DATA_CONTENT
FROM [TABLE] T
OUTER APPLY T.xmlIn.nodes('methodResponse/params/param/value/struct/member') as X(Y)
```

It doesn't give errors but return nulls for both fields. Can someone help?

Comment: The above *would* give an error, specifically `XQuery [T.xmlIn.value()]: Invalid source character '\' (0x5c)`. It should be `value/string` (forward slash, not back slash)

Comment: Thank you @Larnu but it was typo error. I used "\" in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton identifiers aren't correct. For example `(name)[3]` would reference the 3rd `name` node in **each** of the `member` nodes. Each member only has 1 `name` node, so hence the `NULL` value.

You need to reference the 3rd and 4th `member` nodes respectively:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>SubscriberBalanceBefore</name>
            <value>
              <string>0.0</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>TimeStamp</name>
            <value>
              <dateTime.iso8601>20200812T12:31:10</dateTime.iso8601>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>Subsc riberMSISDN</name>
            <value>
              <string>83000000</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>TransactionID</name>
            <value>
              <string>8035768</string>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>'

SELECT X.Y.value('(member[3]/value/string/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as NAME_FIELD, --Does this need to be a varchar(MAX)? Why not an int?
       X.Y.value('(member[4]/value/string/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') DATA_CONTENT --Does this need to be a varchar(MAX)? Why not an int?
FROM (VALUES(@XML))T(xmlIn)
OUTER APPLY T.xmlIn.nodes('methodResponse/params/param/value/struct') as X(Y);
```

Note the above solution, however, depends on that the ordinal position of the nodes. Using XPATH and some boolean logic, you can avoid that:

```sql
SELECT X.Y.value('(member[name/text()="Subsc riberMSISDN"]/value/string/text())[1]', 'int') as NAME_FIELD,
       X.Y.value('(member[name/text()="TransactionID"]/value/string/text())[1]', 'int') DATA_CONTENT
FROM (VALUES(@XML))T(xmlIn)
OUTER APPLY T.xmlIn.nodes('methodResponse/params/param/value/struct') as X(Y);
```